# Assign fixed position to an icon inside a button?

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a button with a Fontawesome icon inside of it, as bullet that I want to be always on the right of the button's text. [See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw6ce83o/)

Let's say I always want that icon to be in a fixed distance of 6px from the left edge of the button.

I can't figure how to do that, so right now I'm using `right:150px` as the positioning value, but this only fits the dimensions of a certain button, according to the text inside of it. Once I change the text to longer/shorter, the icon would move as well.

How can I make it fixed? 
(I don't remember if my current code works well on IE7/8 in the first place, but if it does, I want the solution to work with these versions as well).

HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="button-area">
  <label>
    <span class="fa fa-eye fa-lg bullet"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Changing Text">
  </label>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.button-area{float:left;margin-left:5px;position:relative;padding-bottom:8px}

.button{display:inline-block;zoom:1;line-height:normal;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:baseline;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-drag:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;font-family:inherit;font-family:'Open Sans',arial;font-size:17px;padding:.6em .8em .5em 1.8em;text-decoration:none;border-radius:4px}
.button{color:#fff;background-color:green}

label{display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}

.bullet{position:absolute;height:11px;top:15px;right:150px;width:3px;color:white;font-size:1em !important;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i read your question right, you want the `.bullet` span to be 6px from the left, but you are using `right:150px;` to place it?
Why dont you just use `left:6px;`, thats what it is for.
[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw6ce83o/1/)

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, I really don't remember what was the historical reason I used `right` in the first place, perhaps on some occasions which I can't remember right now simply changing to `left` didn't necessarily work. so with `left`, the rest of the code seems to be like the best practice to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough. when you using font based icons you just have to treat your image as if it were a single letter from a font.

that means. Don't give it any width. If you want to make it bigger use `font-size` and then. If you want to make the position of your single "letter" absolute, it's fine (although I would prefer other ways). Just remove your "width" from your css and add `left:6px` insteed of right.

for your next fiddles I recomend you to make it a bit cleared (a propertie for line) as it's hard to look it easily as you have it right now.

I just change this css:

```
.bullet{position:absolute;height:11px;top:15px;left:6px;color:white;font-size:1em !important;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2)}
```

**EDITED:** I am adding one of my comments as I think it may relevant to make a better use of html/css (imho)

> But it you really want it to do it really right.. insteed of an
>   input.. and if you can't use simple links ( a tag) then use button tag
>   insteed. because you could do something like this:
>   https://jsfiddle.net/gw6ce83o/5/, your users now can click everywhere
>   in your button (insteed of just the input) and there's a very high
>   posibilitie your submit will works the same (programming) than it does
>   your input atm

updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gw6ce83o/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me what other ways exist? I would like to know what is the best practice.

Comment: Well yes I can but It means to remake all css in your case. Give always  the style you desire to the parent, in this case `button-area` (background color, border, shadow if any, paddings etc) treat it as a empty box with no width. Then just, if you want to keep the html, give both your elements inside `display:inline-block` so they both act as "letters" and, as you did overwrite any propertie your `inputs`have in your css (or default browsers). then just add padding left to your "icon" (6px) and the rest will follow the flow

Comment: But it you really want it to do it really right.. insteed of an input.. and if you can't use simple links (<a>) then use <button>`tag insteed. because you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gw6ce83o/5/, your users now can click everywhere in your button (insteed of just the input) and there's a very high posibilitie your submit will works the same (programming) than it does your input atm

Comment: thanks but I think I must use `input` though, as the original form contains `input name` and `value` fields, which must be submitted. what is the main advatnage of styling the parent rather than what I have atm? I use the `button-area` simply the position the button itself, and thus I wouldn't want that area to contain visible styles such as background colors, shadows, etc.

Comment: the main advantage of button insteed of input is that t you can do with it as you like with css (anything you like) while inputs are very limited (including a simple background image it's not possible)..

Comment: but the best example I just gave it to you. You can include inside whatever text plus anthing you want because as a link you have a close tag to "cover" your desire elements. And yes.. as I said... your "submit", "name" and "value" fields may work the same with button as with input, just try it out before discarting it. My "prgramming mates" use often inputs `type="submit"` before I have to style their messes and When I change it to button the "click" work as well.